# How to add a picture to Legrand Orange Book's header and footer

Tags: errors, header-footer, fancyhdr

I tried to put a picture to Legrand Orange Book's header and footer by slightly modifying the `structure.tex`.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Required for header and footer configuration

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sffamily\normalsize\bfseries #1}{}} % Chapter text font settings
%I do not want sectionmark%\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sffamily\normalsize\thesection\hspace{5pt}#1}{}} % Section text font settings
\fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sffamily\normalsize\thepage} % Font setting for the page number in the header
%%\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark} % Print the nearest section name on the left side of odd pages
%%\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark} % Print the current chapter name on the right side of even pages
\fancyhead[C]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{%
    \includegraphics[height=0.5in]{./Gambar/HEADER)
}
\fancyfoot[C]{\includegraphics[height=0.5in]{./Gambar/footer1}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} % Width of the rule under the header
\addtolength{\headheight}{2.5pt} % Increase the spacing around the header slightly
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % Removes the rule in the footer
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhead{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}} % Style for when a plain pagestyle is specified

% Removes the header from odd empty pages at the end of chapters
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{
\clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\fi}
```

but I got no picture on both places.

```
I got this on my log:
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fancyhdr\fancyhdr.sty")
Runaway argument?
{\includegraphics [height=0.5in]{./Gambar/HEADER) } \fancyfoot [C]{\includegrap
hics \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \f@ncyhf was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.90 

? 

Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 13.59999pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

What am I supposed to do?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX Doty! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: I just realized that I made a mistake. I have written: \includegraphics[height=0.5in]{./Gambar/HEADER) <---  I changed to } then it works, but I do not know how to adjust the header and footer height .... anyone knows?

Comment: `\setlength\headheight{0.5in}` and `\setlength\footskip{\dimexpr 0.5in + 12pt\relax}`, for instance (there exists no \footheight length, only a distance from the bottom of the body text to the baseline of the footer). This is most easily done with the `geometry` package.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo in the input